# About Norm of an element $x$ and Norm of an element in its Dual

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

We have Banach Space $B$ and choose $x\in B$ then $||x|| _ B = {\sup}_{T \in B'} \frac {|T(x)|}{||T|| _ {B'}}$

I know I should write something about question but I couldn't move. Suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Hahn-Banach Theorem? The least you can do is say that $\sup_{T\in B'}\frac{|T(x)|}{||T||}\leq ||x||$

Comment: Yes I know H-B Theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:-Define $f:\Bbb{K}x\to\Bbb{K}$ by $f(\lambda x)=\lambda||x||$ . Then $||f||=1$. Now what would the Hahn-Banach Extension of $f$ do?

Also notice that $||\frac{T}{||T||}||=1$ (the norms are operator norms).

Answer (score 0):

We always have $|| Tx || \le ||T|| ||x||$ in other words this is what stated in comment.

For the other part, just use the fact that can be obtained from Hahn-Banach Theorem. More detaily, look at hint in answer and that $f$ whose norm is $1$ is certainly smaller than $\sup ||Tx|| / || T ||$.

That two implies equality.